# How to test a maven plugin (Mojo) from a other module

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I'm creating a maven plugin (Mojo). I've finished my mojo and wrote some test cases for it. The next step is to create integration tests.
The maven plugin is a module inside a bigger project which already has an integration test module.

**My question**: Is there a way to test a maven plugin from another module?

The stack trace I get when I run my integration test which are in another module than my maven plugin:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running nl.ciber.webshare.integration.plugin.MavenPluginIT
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.ConfigurationException: Cannot find a configuration element for a plugin with an artifactId of webshare-integration-tests.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.extractPluginConfiguration(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:619)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.extractPluginConfiguration(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:582)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.testing.AbstractMojoTestCase.lookupMojo(AbstractMojoTestCase.java:353)
        at nl.ciber.webshare.integration.plugin.MavenPluginIT.test(MavenPluginIT.java:35)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)
        at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
        at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
        at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)
        at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:367)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:274)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:290)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:242)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:121)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.948 sec <<< FAILURE! - in nl.ciber.webshare.integration.plugin.MavenPluginIT
test(nl.ciber.webshare.integration.plugin.MavenPluginIT)  Time elapsed: 1.793 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Cannot find a configuration element for a plugin with an artifactId of webshare-integration-tests.
        at nl.ciber.webshare.integration.plugin.MavenPluginIT.test(MavenPluginIT.java:39)
```

My integration test:

```
public class MavenPluginIT extends AbstractMojoTestCase {


    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.tearDown();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {

        try {
            ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
            File pom = new File(classLoader.getResource("simple-sws-plugin/pom.xml").getFile());
            ShareMojo shareMojo = (ShareMojo) lookupMojo("share-file", pom);
            shareMojo.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

My Settings stub:

```
public class SettingsStub extends Settings {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5812009259225888897L;

    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "rawtypes"})
    @Override
    public List getProxies() {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    @Override
    public Server getServer(String name) {
        Server server = null;
        if ("webshare".equals(name)) {
            server = new Server();
            server.setPassword("");
        }
        return server;
    }

}
```

My project stub:

```
public class ShareStub extends MavenProjectStub {
    /**
     * Default constructor
     */


    public ShareStub() {
        MavenXpp3Reader pomReader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model;
        try {
            model = pomReader.read(ReaderFactory.newXmlReader(new File(getPomdir(), "pom.xml")));
            setModel(model);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        setGroupId(model.getGroupId());
        setArtifactId(model.getArtifactId());
        setVersion(model.getVersion());
        setName(model.getName());
        setUrl(model.getUrl());
        setPackaging(model.getPackaging());

        Build build = new Build();
        build.setFinalName(model.getArtifactId());
        build.setDirectory(getBasedir() + "/target");
        build.setSourceDirectory(getBasedir() + "/src/main/java");
        build.setOutputDirectory(getBasedir() + "/target/classes");
        build.setTestSourceDirectory(getBasedir() + "/src/test/java");
        build.setTestOutputDirectory(getBasedir() + "/target/test-classes");

        model.setBuild(build);

        List compileSourceRoots = new ArrayList();
        compileSourceRoots.add(getBasedir() + "/src/main/java");
        setCompileSourceRoots(compileSourceRoots);

        List testCompileSourceRoots = new ArrayList();
        testCompileSourceRoots.add(getBasedir() + "/src/test/java");
        setTestCompileSourceRoots(testCompileSourceRoots);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public File getPomdir() {
        return new File(super.getBasedir() + "/src/test/resources/simple-sws-plugin/");
    }
}
```

Test project pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>nl.ciber.webshare.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Fake testing pom</name>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0.3</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nl.ciber.webshare</groupId>
            <artifactId>webshare-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>nl.ciber.webshare</groupId>
                <artifactId>webshare-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <configuration>
                    <settings implementation="nl.ciber.webshare.integration.plugin.Stubs.SettingsStub"/>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>share-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Project structure:

```
Maven plugin:
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   └───java
│   │       └───nl
│   │           └───ciber
│   │               └───maven
│   │                   └───plugin
│   │                       │   ShareMojo.java
│   │                       │
│   │                       └───utils
│   │                               GlobUtils.java
│   │                               ZipUtils.java
│   │
│   └───test
│       ├───java
│       │   └───nl
│       │       └───ciber
│       │           └───maven
│       │               └───plugin
│       │                   │   MojoTest.java
│       │                   │
│       │                   └───Stubs
│       │                           SettingsStub.java
│       │                           ShareStub.java
│       │
│       └───resources
│           └───simple-sws-plugin
│                   pom.xml

Integration test:
├───src
│   └───test
│       ├───java
│       │   └───nl
│       │       └───ciber
│       │           └───webshare
│       │               └───integration
│       │                   │
│       │                   └───plugin
│       │                       │   MavenPluginIT.java
│       │                       │
│       │                       └───Stubs
│       │                               SettingsStub.java
│       │                               ShareStub.java
│       │
│       └───resources
│           │   init.sql
│           │   test.txt
│           │   test1.txt
│           │   test2.txt
│           │   test3.txt
│           │
│           └───simple-sws-plugin
│                   pom.xml
│
└─
```

Comment: You should put the integration tests into the same module where you plugin lives...furthermore having a plugin building within a larger project will not work. You need to separate your plugin from the rest of the projects...I would suggest to take a look into other plugins like [maven-ear-plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-ear-plugin/src/it/) or other plugins and take a deep look into maven-invoker-plugin for integration tests....

Comment: Okay, as I already suspected. Thank you for your comment. If you are sure you may answer this question so I can accept it. Will defiantly look into the other mvn plugin's @khmarbaise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the integration tests into the same module where you plugin lives.
Furthermore having a plugin building within a larger project will not work cause than you are building your plugin with your code and try to use it with this build which means you will not be able having a release of your plugin which means a stable version which you can reference in your build.

The best approach is to separate your plugin from the rest of the projects and do the testing etc. inside the plugin project after finishing your testing you can make a release of your plugin and than you can use that in your project.

I would suggest to take a look into other plugins like [maven-ear-plugin](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/trunk/maven-ear-plugin/src/it/) or other plugins and take a deep look into [maven-invoker-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/index.html) for integration tests....

If you use maven-invoker plus [mock-repository manger](http://www.mojohaus.org/mrm/mrm-maven-plugin/) than you can test a plugin very good. It is never a good idea to make a separate project for integration tests of a plugin...As an example you can reference the [versions-maven-plugin](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/) which uses the mock repository manager etc.

Answer (score 0):

Mojos are supposed to have and have only concrete logic to accomplish your custom job in addition to what maven's different phases do. While running any maven goal, everything is being done/provided by maven and in case we want to test if plugin works fine we have to enable same context and environment.

Having integration test cases out of plugin is not right thing I guess. But on the contrary to ensure that plugin accomplish the job it's expected to, need to be tested as well. That I think it's good to go with a different module having only integration test cases for your plugin.

Comment: If you use maven-invoker plus [mock-repository manger](http://www.mojohaus.org/mrm/mrm-maven-plugin/) than you can test a plugin very good. It is never a good idea to make a separate project for integration tests of a plugin...

Comment: Okay, thankyou for your information and thoughts.
I agree that creating another module for integration tests should be good to go. But that doesn't answer my question. I wanted to know if it's possible and how to achieve it. But after the comment of @khmarbaise I believe it isn't meant to do it from another module. I also looked into other plugins from maven self and they all use another method of testing compared to mine. they also keep integration tests and project together.

Comment: @khmarbaise could you create an answer for this question so I can approve it. you helped me a lot with resolving my problem. Thankyou.